# How to format declared attributes in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables that inherit from a base model. The table arguments are giving me a fit and I am struggling with the declared attribute to make it work.

```
class Analysis_Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    __tablename__ = 'analysis'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement='auto')
    experimentNr = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=False, unique=False, index=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(64))
    filedata = db.Column(db.Text)
    last_updated_by = db.Column(db.Text, default=get_user_email, onupdate=get_user_email, server_default='None')
    __table_args__ = (db.Index('analysis_eidx', "experimentNr"), )

class Analysis(Analysis_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'analysis'

class Analysis_Audit(Analysis_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'analysis_audit'
    type = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
```

Can someone please help and any explanation on the solution would be greatly appreciated!